# Vue router - passing in a prop Array into a router view with id

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have looked at the examples and I still cant figure this out.

I have two views: MyFormsView and FormDetailsView. I am trying to pass in an object from the MyFormsView into the FormDetailsView as a prop so that I can then access the data inside of it and display relavent things.

My router file has the following relevant entry:

```
const routes = [{
path: "/form/:id",
name: "formDetails",
component: FormDetailsView, 
props: true,
}]
```

MyFormsView looks like this: (basically a list of links coming from my forms array)

```
<template>
    <h1>My Forms</h1>
    <div v-for="form in forms" :key="form.id" class="form">
        <router-link
            :to="{
                name: 'formDetails',
                params: { id: form.id },
                props: { formObj: form },
            }"
        >
            <h2>{{ form.title }}</h2>
        </router-link>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            forms: [
                { title: "Form 1", id: 1, details: "lorem" },
                { title: "Form 2", id: 2, details: "lorem" },
                { title: "Form 3", id: 3, details: "lorem" },
            ],
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

FormDetailsView looks like this: (idea is that I can get the whole object and extract anything I want using .dot notation)

```
<template>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>Form Details Page</h1>
        <p>Editing form with ID: {{ id }}</p> // This works and shows the correct ID 
        <p>Title: {{ formObj.title }}</p> // This doesnt work and gives an error saying cant get title from undefined

        <div class="left-container container" ref="left">
            <h3>Form Contents</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right-container container" ref="right"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "formDetails",
    props: ["id", "formObj"],
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.formObj); // Gives undefined
    },
};
</script>
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set props as object type, you can set you object in props instead of true. For more information:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question of mine - I dont think what I was trying to do is possible, or if it is, it probably isnt the right way to go about it - I instead ended up using the Vuex store functionality and had my object in there where I can access it from both places without having to specifically pass it in.